# JWT authorization laravel / angularjs issue

Tags: php, angularjs, authentication, laravel-5.1

So I am trying to create a basic JWT token authentication.

I am using Laravel as my backend API with tymon/jwt-auth for creating tokens / refreshing tokens and providing middleware to check for tokens.

I am using AngularJS with Satellizer to store the returned token in local storage and send said token for all future requests.

I am using Laravel 5.1 / Jwt-auth 0.5.* / AngularJs 1.4.7 / Satellizer (latest).

I log in and the token is stored in my local storage. I then try to make a call to authentcate's index to "get all users" and the authorization header is there with `Bearer <token stored in local storage>` but I get the response of "token_not_provided" almost as if the middleware is not looking in the authorization header for the token. Here is some of my code. I am following https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps.

**AuthenticateController.php:**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use App\User;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        // Apply the jwt.auth middleware to all methods in this controller
        // except for the authenticate method. We don't want to prevent
        // the user from retrieving their token if they don't already have it
        $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['authenticate']]);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        // Retrieve all the users in the database and return them
        $users = User::all();
        return $users;
    }

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm suffering from this issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I have looked into this for weeks with still no solution. 48 views and no solution. hrmmmm

Comment: I found a solution, I just don't remember what it is. Let me think on it. Do you use Apache?

Comment: yessir....lamp environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Apache, you need to set the .htaccess to not crop out the Authorization header.

Open the .htaccess at `path/to/your/project/public/.htaccess` and add this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Mine is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On        

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```